# Possible to remove tag item from Literal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the below code

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        class Customer
        {
            public Customer(int id, string fName)
            {
                ID = id;
                FirstName = fName;
            }

            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
        }

        private List<Customer> GetCustomerNames()
        {
            // Add Customers to list - this is essentially coming from a database
            List<Customer> Names = new List<Customer>();
            Names.Add(new Customer(1, "Name 1"));
            Names.Add(new Customer(2, "Name 2"));
            Names.Add(new Customer(3, "Name 3"));
            Names.Add(new Customer(4, "Name 4"));

            return Names;
        }

        private void DropdownNames()
        {
            // Set the dropdown
            ddlName.DataSource = GetCustomerNames();
            ddlName.DataTextField = "FirstName";
            ddlName.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlName.DataBind();
        }

        private void SetNameHTML(List<Customer> Names)
        {
            // The below code would set the literal control with the values coming from the list along with custom span so the design would be correct
            Int32 Count = 0;
            lit1.Text = string.Empty;

            foreach (Customer c in Names)
            {
                if (Count == 0)
                {
                    // IF first element then set active class so correct style is applied
                    lit1.Text += string.Format("<span class='square active' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='{0}'>{1}</span> <br />", c.FirstName, c.ID);
                    spName.InnerText = c.FirstName;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Other non selected items - Note no active listed in the class
                    lit1.Text += string.Format("<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='{0}'>{1}</span> <br />", c.FirstName, c.ID);
                }

                Count += 1;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DropdownNames();
                SetNameHTML(GetCustomerNames());
            }

        }

        protected void ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get customer names again as the list would be empty if the SetNameHTML is removed
            var CustomerNames = GetCustomerNames();
            SetNameHTML(CustomerNames);
            // Get a single customer to set the correct class (square active)
            var CustName = CustomerNames.Where(cid => cid.ID == Convert.ToInt32(ddlName.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault();
            spName.InnerText = ddlName.SelectedItem.Text;

            // += on lit1.Text so that the span list is not empty. 
            // If i remove the lin SetNameHTML(CustomerNames); above then the list is empty
            lit1.Text = string.Format("<span class='square active' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='{0}'>{1}</span> <br />", CustName.FirstName, CustName.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <span class="info" runat="server" id="spName"></span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <div class="squares">
                <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the literal control so i can add the relevant span depending on the number of names found. Please note ive stripped out majority of the CSS JS which is why it may look plain.

When i select an item from the dropdown it adds the item again (if you run the above code you will know what i mean)

Note my comments and why i have done what i have.

Heres the view source of when the page loads and then once i select an item

Load

```
<div class="squares">

<span class='square active' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 1'>1</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 2'>2</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 3'>3</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 4'>4</span> <br />

            </div>
```

First item selected

```
<div class="squares">

<span class='square active' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 1'>1</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 2'>2</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 3'>3</span> <br />
<span class='square' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 4'>4</span> <br />
<span class='square active' ID='spName' runat='server' data-value='Name 2'>2</span> <br />

            </div>
```

I know why this is happening but im not sure how to go about this. What i want to do is not add the selected item to the list again but since im using a literal control i dont know how to remove it or if there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: You could try adding you spans as actual controls instead of just an html string in your code behind and you might have better luck. Like this: `var span = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("span");` then add your attribute: `span.Attributes.Add("data-value", c.ID);` then just add the new span control to the literal: `lit1.Controls.Add(span);`

Comment: Change your literal to placeholder instead

Comment: As @pho3nix said, you should probably use a placeholder control. The `<asp:PlaceHolder />` renders as a `<div />` so you should replace your "squares" div with a placeholder then add the spans to that. Like this: `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phSquares" runat="server" CssClass="squares">`

Comment: @zgood - As you could see, I had posted an answer suggesting the PlaceHolder (before pho3nix's comment, as a matter of fact). By the way, the PlaceHolder is not rendered as a div. Its content is rendered in the page without an additional container (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743404/whats-the-difference-between-placeholder-and-div).

Comment: @ConnorsFan yup you are correct... I was thinking of `<asp:Panel />`. Sorry I did not see you answer. In my comment above just replace "PlaceHolder" with "Panel" and that should work.

Comment: @zgood Placeholdrr dont generate any container what generate a div is Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the Literal control by a PlaceHolder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server" />
```

And add ASP.NET Label controls in it, which are rendered as `span` elements in the HTML output, or ASP.NET Panel controls, which are rendered as `div` elements.

That way, you will work with controls instead of inserting raw HTML code in a Literal, which is more difficult to manage.

**UPDATE**

The new Labels must be added to the PlaceHolder on each postback, not inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` conditional block. Each ID must also be unique (or you can leave the ID property empty). I mention it because I see several `span` elements with the ID `spname` in your markup sample.

In a simple case, it would look like this:

```
private int labelSuffix = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.ID = string.Format("span_{0}", labelSuffix++);
    lbl.Attributes.Add("data-value", "Name 1");
    lbl.CssClass = "square";
    lbl.Text = "1";
    ph1.Controls.Add(lbl);
    ...
}
```

The Label can then be retrieved in another event handler:

```
protected void btnPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // By the ID of the control
    Label lbl = ph1.FindControl("MyLabel") as Label;
    lbl.Text = "With some new text";

    // Or by looping on the controls collection
    foreach (Label lbl in ph1.Controls)
    {
        lbl.Text = "And another text";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a placeholder seems to be helping! Currently I've added a label assigned the text as the same as what i had for the literal control and added it to the PH control collection. Problem at present is when i select a value from the DD it doesnt change the value of the span even though in codebehind when in debug mode i can see the line being executed?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a simple usage of the PlaceHolder.

Comment: Thx! I tried with a label which was working nicely but the problem i had with the label is when it renders it add its own span tag. I cant add the relevant span HTML within this tag even though i use the Text property? So i changed to a Literal control which again was working but the ID of the control is always the same even though im adding a new Literal and setting the ID. I will see if i can amend the page load as you suggested to see what happens.

Comment: You can let the Label render its span tag without adding one in its content. That is the idea of using a Label: not having to manage the tag yourself. Just set the the Text property and add a `data-value` attribute. I updated my answer again to show that. I also showed how you can define a variable that will ensure a different ID for each Label.

Comment: THANKS!! this did it. Appreciate your patience on this.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding value (or on change event) check if it doesn't exist like

```
if (!ddlName.Items.Contains("ValueToAdd"))
{//add value in dropdown list}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replying. The item re-adds itself to the literal control. Not the dropdown list.